# How to make my URL custom defined ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I have developed a webform in asp.net which is deployed online and has URL like `www.mywebsite.com/complaints.aspx`

but i want to make this URL like this

```
www.mywebsite.com/complaints.aspx?AreaCode=90
```

and also want to access ID on `complaints.aspx` page.

The area code will always remain 90 and will never change and if it has to be change then i will manually change it.

I can't figure this out.

Comment: Huh? You mean **var num = Request("AreaCode")**

Comment: @JeremyThompson Yes sir but on the same page.

Comment: I don't understand, please elaborate as best you can

Comment: see, I first visit my page, complaint.aspx, now it should appear as www.mywebsite.com/complaints.aspx?AreaCode=90 by default every time.

Comment: Google: "Helicon ISAPI rewrite"

Comment: @JeremyThompson ok sir and how about HttpContext.RewritePath

Comment: You could do it that way, though at the ISAPI level it's much earlier in the pipeline

Comment: @JeremyThompson sir I have used this in Page_Load but doesn't change the URL in bar

Comment: you said you  want to access ID. What is ID?

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look for routing in ASP.Net

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/url-routing

Comment: How does that answer the question? Example please

Comment: i missed the part that it should be 90 all the time, just recognize the routing part. But why dont you just set the 90 in your controller? But maybe you could have a look at this https://github.com/haacked/routemagic

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Context.RewritePath("/complaints.aspx?AreaCode=90");

Comment: That's heaps inefficient

Comment: @JeremyThompson sir I have used this in Page_Load but doesn't change the URL in bar